# android Layout design dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I am trying to design ui part in android ...there is one layout which hold an image..and go for another view which create element dynamically on same layout...my dynamic layout works well but static one not show...In short I want dynamic one on static layout with the image. My code is:

```
  public class CircleView extends RelativeLayout {

    static final int centerId = 100;
    static final int center = 110;
    private final int radius;
    ImageView image=new ImageView(getContext());

    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createNewRelativeLayoutParams() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //image.setLayoutParams(lp);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
        //image.setLayoutParams(lp);

        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, centerId);
        lp.addRule(RIGHT_OF, centerId);

        return lp;
    }


    private View prepareElementForCircle(View elem, int distX, int distY) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = createNewRelativeLayoutParams();


        elem.measure(0, 0);
        int deltaX = elem.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int deltaY = elem.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        lp.setMargins(distX - deltaX, 0, 0, radius - distY - deltaY);
        elem.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return elem;
    }


    public CircleView(Context context, int radius, View[] elements) {
        super(context);
        this.radius = radius;

        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.setLayoutParams(lpView);*/

        View center = new View(context);
        center.setId(centerId);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, 0);
        lpcenter.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        lpcenter.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
        center.setLayoutParams(lpcenter);

        //center.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);
        this.addView(center);
        //ImageView tt=new ImageView(this);

        this.addView(prepareElementForCircle(elements[0], 0, 0));
        if (elements.length % 2 == 0) {
            this.addView(prepareElementForCircle(elements[elements.length / 2],
                    0, 2 * radius));
        }
        if (elements.length > 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= (elements.length - 1) / 2; i++) {
                int y = i * 4 * radius / elements.length;
                int x = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2)
                        - Math.pow((radius - y), 2));
                this.addView(prepareElementForCircle(elements[i], x, y));
                this.addView(prepareElementForCircle(elements[elements.length
                        - i], -x, y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how i can make this dynamic layout transparent..